# count each character for each word in a string and put the word with less than 5 characters in array using php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

**How can I, in this order:**

```
- remove the period from the end of words in a string
- put all the words that are less than 5 characters in an array
- eliminate duplicate words
```

and then return the results. for example:

**I program like I write stories.**

```
$results = ('I', 'like', 'write' );
```

*notice, all words have less than 5 characters, and there is only one "I" because duplicates were removed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = 'I program like I write stories.';
$string = preg_replace("/\.$/", "", $string);// remove the period from the end.
$words = explode(" " ,$string);// split string into words
foreach ($words as $wordIndex => $word) {
    if (strlen($word) > 5) { // if the length of the string is greater than 5, remove it
        unset($words[$wordIndex]);// remove the word
        }
    }
var_dump(array_unique($words));// only print the unique elements in the array
```

And this would print:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'I' (length=1)
  2 => string 'like' (length=4)
  4 => string 'write' (length=5)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression to match words that have 5 or less characters:

```
/\b[a-z]{1,5}\b/i
```

- `\b` is used to make the match happens only at the boundary of words.

---

Use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get array with duplicated values removed:

```
$text = "remove the period from the end of words in a string";
preg_match_all('/\b[a-z]{1,5}\b/i', $text, $matches);
print_r(array_unique($matches[0]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => the
    [1] => from
    [3] => end
    [4] => of
    [5] => words
    [6] => in
    [7] => a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method to get the expected results:

```
$string = 'I program like I write stories.';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$results = [];
foreach ($words as $position => $word) {
    $word = rtrim(trim($word), '.');
    if (strlen($word) && strlen($word) <= 5 && !in_array($word, $results)) {
        $results[] = $word;
    }
}
var_dump($results);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "I"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "like"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "write"
}
```